# How to write the .htaccess rules to redirect all urls to new url after a change in the directory name?

Tags: .htaccess

I renamed a directory on my website. How can I redirect all the existing urls to the new urls.

For example, I renamed "MyFolder" to "mydirectory". So, how can I redirect http://mywebsite.com/MyFolder/somepage.html to http://mywebsite.com/mydirectory/somepage.html and http://mywebsite.com/MyFolder/anotherpage.html to http://mywebsite.com/mydirectory/anotherpage.html etc. using some rules in .htaccess file.

The following is the content of my .htaccess file. It's with some other rules of WordPress.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/Wordpress/(.*)$ http://example.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So `RewriteRule ^/Wordpress/(.*)$ http://example.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]` should work as per my knowledge. But it's not working.

Interestingly the following rule solved my problem. But I would like to learn how.

```
Redirect 301 /Wordpress/ http://example.com/wordpress/
```

Please let me know how this works.

Comment: First you need to put your rule before word press rule `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`, Second, you nedd to remove the first slash in your rule : `RewriteRule ^Wordpress/(.*)$ http://example.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]` (and if you are redirecting to the same domain, you don't need the `http://example.com` part )

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems.

When matching URLs in .htaccess it is important to remember that the value you are matching in your RewriteRule is a relative path, not a full URI (i.e. it won't include the root slash). You could either remove it, or make it optional to make your code transferable between VirtualHosts and .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/?Wordpress/(.*)$ http://example.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Your second problem is that you have a RewriteRule that matches all URLs and has the L flag before your new rule. The L flag makes it the last rule processed so your new RewriteRule can never be triggered, move it to just after the RewriteBase.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/Wordpress/(.*)$ http://example.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Finally what I don't quite understand (but is probably due to you creating a fictitious example) is that if you have moved the Wordpress directory, you will have no look having the redirect inside your Wordpress .htaccess file, since requests to the old path won't hit the file if it's moved.